# Why is my code returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, promise

### Background

In my code I am making a GET request to a mockup db (using mocky) using promises.

I expect to get a JSON object after parsing the response, but instead I am getting something else.

### Problem

The problem is that my code, for some reason, returns a `Promise` (I think) instead of the JSON value it should.

### Code

```
let request = require("request");
let Promise = require("promise");
let HTTPGet = Promise.denodeify(request);

let dbData = 
HTTPGet("http://www.mocky.io/v2/57fbba4c0f0000f4124fd451")
.then(response => JSON.parse(response.body));
```

This code will do set `dbData` equal to `Object {_45: 0, _81: 1, _65: Object, _54: null}`.

However, the following code will give me the expected result:

```
let request = require("request");
let Promise = require("promise");
let HTTPGet = Promise.denodeify(request);

let dbData; 
HTTPGet("http://www.mocky.io/v2/57fbba4c0f0000f4124fd451")
.then(response => {dbData = JSON.parse(response.body);});
```

### Question

1. According to my understanding of promises, the `then` statement returns either a Promise, or the result of a promise via `return`. Since in the first code snippet I am returning a JSON object, why is not `dbData` equal to that object?
2. How can I fix the first code snippet (in a more elegant way?)

Comment: I don't understand. You're saying both pieces of code work?

Comment: you are asigning to dbData a promise, and then doing .then on that promise.
If you want to asign the result to dbData you have to do it inside the .then function

Comment: You are getting a promise *for* the json value. That's how it is supposed to work. `then` *always* returns a promise - the future result of the future computation.

Comment: @yBrodsky Not true. His first example is working as you would expect it to, setting `dbData` to the return value of the function. Much like `a = add(x,y)`

Comment: Don't you mean to return the result of JSON.parse()?  That is, what happens if you add a return to the function body?

Comment: @Jack a = add(x, y) is not the same, that returns a value. His example dbData is always a promise. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/zqn3p6c5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to my understanding of promises, the then statement returns either a Promise, or the result of a promise via return.

No. It *always* returns a promise.

The return value (or lack thereof) of the callback function will determine what is passed into the `then` handler for the returned promise.

> How can I fix the first code snippet (in a more elegant way?)

Process the data inside the `then` handler (or return the promise and process the data in a later `then` handler).

Answer (score 0):

`then` does ALWAYS return a promise. Your second code snippet is the way to go in this case.

Comment: Not really. The way to go is to wait for the promise whereever you need the value.

Comment: True. What I mean is there is not a 'more elegant' way to get the response into `dbData`.

Answer (score -1):

```
'use strict';
let request = require("request");
let Promise = require("promise");
let HTTPGet = Promise.denodeify(request);
let co = require('co');

let dbData;
const gen = co(function *(){
       let response = yield HTTPGet("http://www.mocky.io/v2/57fbba4c0f0000f4124fd451");
       dbData = yield JSON.parse(response.body);
});

gen.then(function(){
  //dbData is available
  console.log(dbData);
})
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer